# Placing and accessing images outside app/webroot at Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I am currently saving uploaded images at */cakephp/uploads/* instead of doing it inside */cakephp/app/webroot/imgs/*.

When i try to access the image by URL, with something like this:

```
http://myweb.com/cakephp/uploads/imageName.jpg
```

It shows a 404 error. I guess, due to the *.htaccess*, or more concretely, to the *web.config* file that i use under windows with ISS7.

Is there any way to access to them without modifying the *web.config* file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is my understanding that anything **not** placed in the `webroot` folder cannot be accessed directly via a url. To access files outside of the webroot, you can use [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html).

I'd just put your `uploads` folder inside your `APP` folder, `http://myweb.com/cakephp/app/uploads`

then just adjust `path` to `path => APP . 'uploads' . DS`

It's not clear why you want to do this; if you want to just access the images like normal, place the `uploads` in to your `img` directory.

Typically you'd use this approach for serving files etc, allowing user authentication and so on.